# Pre-populated subfields of repeater in Custom Post from subfields repeater in Option Page - Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I want to inseart automatically 2 subfields in repeater handing by option page into 2 of 6 subfields of repeater in custom post.

The subfields can get well. But when I edit the other subfields and upload/publish post, the value will be not saved except values of file name and file type.

Below is my current code.

```
// Pre-populate Students documents repeater field
function my_acf_set_repeater( $value, $post_id, $field ){
    $settings_values = get_field('students-files','option');
    $value = array();
    foreach($settings_values as $settings_value){
        $value[] = array(
            'field_649037ac7d880' => $settings_value['file_name'],
            'field_649037c47d881' => $settings_value['file_type'],
        );
    }
    return $value;
}
add_filter('acf/load_value/key=field_649037737d87f', 'my_acf_set_repeater', 10, 3);
```

Here is some pictures

[repeater option page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KksLC.png)

[repeater for custom post type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7p33.png)

[custom post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2FmP.png)

[option page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eC4du.png)

Anyone has solution for my case, please help! Thank you.

This is a solution for my case. I dont know exactly if it is the best way, but it works for me.

```
// Pre-populate Students documents repeater field
function my_acf_set_repeater($value, $post_id, $field) {
    $settings_values = get_field('students-files', 'option');
    if (empty($value)) {
        $value = array();
        foreach ($settings_values as $settings_value) {
            $value[] = array(
                'field_649037ac7d880' => $settings_value['file_name'],
                'field_649037c47d881' => $settings_value['file_type'],
            );
        }
        return $value;
    }
    return $value;
}

add_filter('acf/load_value/key=field_649037737d87f', 'my_acf_set_repeater', 10, 3);

function populate_custom_fields($post_id) {
    if (get_post_type($post_id) == 'students') {
        // Get the values of the File Name and File Type fields from the options page
        $file_name = get_field('file_name', 'option');
        $file_type = get_field('file_type', 'option');
        // Update or set the values for the custom fields in the custom post type
        update_field('student_document_name', $file_name, $post_id);
        update_field('student_document_type', $file_type, $post_id);
        // Get the existing values of the Require, Upload, Status, and Note fields in the custom post type
        $require = get_field('student_document_require', $post_id);
        $upload = get_field('student_document_upload', $post_id);
        $dueDate = get_field('student_document_due_date', $post_id);
        $status = get_field('student_document_status', $post_id);
        $note = get_field('student_document_note', $post_id);
        // Update or set the values for the Require, Upload, Status, and Note fields in the custom post type
        update_field('student_document_require', $require, $post_id);
        update_field('student_document_upload', $upload, $post_id);
        update_field('student_document_due_date', $dueDate, $post_id);
        update_field('student_document_status', $status, $post_id);
        update_field('student_document_note', $note, $post_id);
    }
}
add_action('acf/save_post', 'populate_custom_fields');
```